# Can someone explain me, why my code is not working?

Tags: c++

I am completely new in C++ and I have to solve a task for college, where I have to make a struct Matrix and fill it with random integers. I marked the line with a "!" where the error appears. 
It is the error C2131(Visual C++ Compiler). It says "expression did not evaluate to a constant".

```
struct Matrix{
   int rows;
   int columns;
   Matrix(int r, int c){
      rows = r, columns = c;
   }
   int produceMatrix(){
       int matrix[rows][columns];  "!"
       for(int i = 0; i != rows; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j != columns; j++){
               matrix[i][j] = rand() %10 +1;
           }
       }
       return 0;
   }
   int showMatrix(){
       for(int i = 0; i != rows; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j != columns; j++){
               cout << matrix[i][j]<< endl;
           }
       }
   }
};


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    Matrix a(3, 4);

}
```

Comment: Because C++ does not have variable-length arrays. `rows` and `columns` need to be compile time constants to work

Comment: I am not that much familiar with C++ as well but I guess it is impossible to define functions inside of structs. You need to use "class" instead

Comment: @mangusta that's completely wrong. `struct` and `class` are the same thing in C++ (except for default access and inheritance modifier)

Comment: @UnholySheep yes, I re-checked the C++ specs, you are right

Comment: @UnholySheep Does that mean that rows and columns need to be specific integers before I run my code ?

Comment: @Josh.K  Take a look at this answer to get started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/3527268

Comment: They need to be either specific integers, or you need to use `std::vector` instead of arrays. Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains to you how to use `std::vector`, and start reading.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know that this is not a tutorial. Currently I am reading the C++ Primer but nevertheless i could not find my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to create your matrix with `rows` and `columns` values only known at runtime, you are better off using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to hold your data, as the static array you use needs to know its size at compile time. But if all your sizes are known at compile time and you just want flexibility of creating different matrix sizes, you can use template, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

template <int ROWS, int COLUMNS>
struct Matrix
{
    int rows = ROWS;
    int columns = COLUMNS;
    int matrix[ROWS][COLUMNS] = {};

    void produceMatrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    void showMatrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                std::cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    Matrix<3,4> a;
    a.produceMatrix();
    a.showMatrix();
}
```

https://ideone.com/rCLxSn

```
4   10  5   5   
3   8   3   6   
2   4   9   10
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing is that you cannot make variable-length arrays this way. 
Another thing is that if you create a variable within a function (like you were doing here with `int matrix` in `produceMatrix()`), it is then not visible in another function.

Therefore, the array containing the elements of the matrix should be declared in your struct there, where you have declared `rows` and `columns`.

To store the elements of your matrix, you can use one-dimensional array of length equal to `rows*columns`.

Now, you need some kind of dynamic array to be able to make it of the length not known in the compilation time. 
One solution is to use a pointer and define an array with `new` operator in the constructor. However, if you use `new`, then you have to use `delete` at some point to deallocate memory, which here means that the destructor is needed. Another problem would be with copying of your matrices.
Another, simpler solution is to use `std::vector`, a container provided by c++ standard library. Here's how to do it with `std::vector` (you need to add `#include<vector>` to your file):

```
struct Matrix{
int rows;
int columns;
vector<int> matrix;

Matrix(int r, int c){
rows = r, columns = c;
matrix = vector<int>(c*r);
}
int produceMatrix(){

    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++){
        matrix[i] = rand() %10 +1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int showMatrix(){
    for(int i = 1; i <= matrix.size(); i++){
        cout << matrix[i-1];
        if(i%columns == 0) cout << endl;
        else cout << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As many people commented, please go through a good C++ book to learn about arrays, classes, structs etc. As for your code, the following might produce what I think you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Matrix
{
    int rows;
    int columns;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;

    Matrix(int r, int c): rows(r), columns(c)
    {
        matrix.resize(r);
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
            matrix[i].resize(c);
    }
    int produceMatrix()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i != rows; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j != columns; j++)
               matrix[i][j] = rand() %10 +1;
        return 0;
    }

    int showMatrix()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i != rows; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j != columns; j++)
                std::cout << matrix[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<'\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    Matrix a(3, 4);
    a.produceMatrix();
    a.showMatrix();
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of "resize" ?

Comment: @Josh.K: resize sets the size of the vector to the value we want, also allocating memory. So later, we can simply refer to the element with the operator[].